# Is there a difference between Principal Component and weighted mean using PC loadings? How to get Principal Component on scale of original variables?

Tags: r, pca, mean, factor-analysis, dimensionality-reduction

I was interested in doing a Principal Component analysis but returning a Principal Component on the scale of the original variables. Principal component analysis in R defaults to scaling and centering, and so I thought that if I set scale and center to False, that it would return a Principal Component on the scale of the original variables. However, this was very much not the case, and the not-scaled and not-centered Principal Component was on a very different scale, confusingly.

I then tried taking a weighted mean using the loadings from the scaled/centered PCA as well as a weighted mean using the loadings from the not-scaled/not-centered PCA. The values of the original dataset were bounded between 1 and 5, and the weighted mean using the scaled/centered PCA exceeded these boundaries and thus appeared not to be on the original scale. Meanwhile, the weighted mean using the not-centered/not-scaled PCA loadings was within the 1 to 5 boundaries of the original scale.

I thus have a few questions:

- What does scaling and centering PCA versus not scaling and centering PCA do?
- Why is PCA *without* scaling and centering not on the scale of the original variables? I would assume that not scaling and centering should return a PCA on scale of original values, but it does not seem that way.
- It seems that a weighted mean using PCA loadings should return a variable identical to the PCA, but on the scale of the original variables. Is that a correct interpretation or is that off?

Below is reproducible code:

```
library(psych)
bfi <- bfi[grep("^A1$",colnames(bfi)):grep("^O5$",colnames(bfi))]
bfi <- bfi[complete.cases(bfi),]


PCA <- prcomp(bfi)

loadingsPCA1 <- PCA$rotation[,1]

rotatedDataPCA1 <- PCA$x[,1]

WM1 <- apply(bfi, 1, function(x) weighted.mean(x, loadingsPCA1))

cor.test(WM1, rotatedDataPCA1)





PCA2 <- prcomp(bfi, scale=F, center=F)

loadingsPCA2 <- PCA2$rotation[,1]

rotatedDataPCA2 <- PCA2$x[,1]

WM2 <- apply(bfi, 1, function(x) weighted.mean(x, loadingsPCA2))

cor.test(WM2, rotatedDataPCA2)


cbind(WM1, rotatedDataPCA1, WM2, rotatedDataPCA2)
```